# Имеет ли родительский блок дочерний блок с определенным классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть родительский блок с классом .parent и в нем может быть или не быть один дочерний блок с классом .child, нужно определить есть ли .child внутри .parent и если есть, то сделать border элементу .parent внутри которого есть .child заленым. У меня почему-то все элементы теперь в зеленом border

```js
$('.parent').each(function() {
  var test = $(this).find('.wrapper');
  if(test.has('.child')){
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid green');
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "child">content</div>
    <div class = "another_child">another content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "child">content</div>
    <div class = "another_child">another content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "another_child">another content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.parent').each(function() {
  var test = $(this).find('.wrapper').has('.child').index();
if(test == 0){
$(this).css('border', '2px solid green');
}

});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "child">content</div>
    <div class = "another_child">another content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "child">content</div>
    <div class = "another_child">another content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "another_child">another content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

jquery всегда возвращает объект jQuery, даже если не нашел ничего. смотрите в объекте length

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
  var test = $(this).find('.wrapper');
  if(test.has('.child').length){
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid green');
  }
});
```

т.е. не if(test.has('.child')), а  if(test.has('.child').length)